# Cannot change the image src for event.target images

Tags: javascript, events

```
<div class = "category_list_11">
            <img src = "./static/images/compre6.png" class = "coffeeimages">
            <div class = "category_list_field">
                <div class = "category_list_field1">
                    <button class = "categoryfieldbutton1">
                    <img src = "./static/images/hm_favorite_2.png" class = "favorite_img1">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class = "category_list_field2">
                    <button class = "categoryfieldbutton2">
                    <img src = "./static/images/hm_2_cart_2.png" class = "favorite_img2">
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

in javascript i tried to add event listener for category_list_field_1

```
var categoryfields = Array.from(category_list_field);

for (let i = 0; i < categoryfields.length; i++) {

categoryfields[i].addEventListener("click", event => {

console.log(event.target.matches(".favorite_img2"))
if(event.target && event.target.matches(".favorite_img2")) {

console.log(event.target.src);

if (event.target.src = "static/images/hm_2_cart_2.png") {

console.log("1");
event.target.src = "static/images/hm_2_cart_2_a.png";
console.log(event.target);

}

if (event.target.src = "static/images/hm_2_cart_2_a.png") {

event.target.src = "static/images/hm_2_cart_2.png";

}
```

I want to make event listener which would make image with class "favorite_img2" change src on click to "hm_2_cart_2_a.png" then go back to previous src on next click. The line

```
console.log(event.target);
```

gives the output `<img src="static/images/hm_2_cart_2.png" class="favorite_img2">`

Sorry for the dreadful formatting.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There are curly brackets and semicolons missing not to mention the painful indentation. Throw it in https://beautifier.io/ next time 

Comment: @asyncawait oh thanks a lot for very helpful tip! will make sure to use it from now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely this line

```js
if (event.target.src = "static/images/hm_2_cart_2.png")
```

inside the parenthesis there should be a comparison operator, instead you are assigning the `.src` which will always be true. You need to use the double equal sign `==` to compare the src to a string.

Comment: oh that was it! wow that was embarassing :D

Comment: Happy to help, always easy once you can see the answer. I didn't do much testing so there may still be other issues. I encourage you to explore [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as well. There are many things that could be done to clean up your code that I don't feel are relevant to this answer. Happy coding!